# Email is send on loading of the app script, but email needed to be send onclick

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have created an app script in which email can be send to the login user and to the email Ids which are mentioned in spreadsheet. The email is send to the active user and to all the mentioned email Ids.
However I want email to be send to login user (which is done) and to the specified email Id when selected via app script.

But the mail is send to all the mentioned email IDs in spreadsheet when the app script is getting loaded, whereas the mail should be send onclick, which is not working.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}


function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('SS ID')
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}

function sendMessage(ManagerID,proNo,proName){
 var email=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var eId=ManagerID;
  var subject="Feedback form initiated" ;
  var message="Feedback form initiated by "+eId;
  var message2="To fill the feedback form please follow the url: ";
  var url="googleform's ID";
  var subject2="Feedback Form";
  MailApp.sendEmail(eId, subject, message);

  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject2,message2+url);
}





//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body onload="document.getElementById('one').style.visibility='hidden'">

  <div id="initiateFb">
  <form>
    <? var data = getData(); ?>
<table border='1px solid black'>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
        <?if(j==(data[i].length-1)&&i!=0) { ?>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Initiate" 
        onclick="document.getElementById('initiateFb').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('one').style.visibility='visible';
        <?var ManagerID=data[i][6];?> <?var proNo=data[i][1];?> <?var proName=data[i][2];?>
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<?=data[i][1] ?>';
        document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='<?=data[i][2] ?>';
        document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML='<?=data[i][3] ?>';
        document.getElementById('div4').innerHTML='<?=data[i][4] ?>';
        document.getElementById('div5').innerHTML='<?=data[i][5] ?>';
        document.getElementById('div6').innerHTML='<?=data[i][6] ?>';
        document.getElementById('div7').innerHTML='<?=data[i][7] ?>';
        document.getElementById('div8').innerHTML='<?=data[i][8] ?>';
        document.getElementById('div9').innerHTML='<?=data[i][9] ?>';
        return false;"/>
        </td>
        <? } ?>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>

</form>
</div>
 <div id="one">
 <form>
 <table>
 <tr>

 <td>ca :</td>
 <td id="div1"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>cb :</td>
 <td id="div2"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>cc:</td>
 <td id="div3"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>cd :</td>
 <td id="div4"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>ce:</td>
 <td id="div5"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>cf:</td>
 <td id="div6"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>cg :</td>
 <td id="div7"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>ch :</td>
 <td id="div8"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>ci:</td>
 <td id="div9"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Initiate Feedback" onclick="<?sendMessage(ManagerID,proNo,proName);?>"/>
 </form>
 </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

I have attached my code.

Comment: Read about difference between client side scripting and server side. <? runs the script on the server side (during loading). To run something after the button is clicked you have to do it asynchronously. So in this case: onclick="<?sendMessage(ManagerID,proNo,proName);?>  should be done rather like this: onclick="google.script.run.sendMessage(..,..,..);"  . The parameters should be read from client side script, from the html elements or whatever.

Comment: thanks for the response @arturro , but I have tried this also its not working. The error shown is cannot find google script.

Answer (score 1):

arturro is correcct in the question comment. To make an asynchronous call you **must** use

```
google.script.run.sendMessage(ManagerID,proNo,proName)
```

However make note that

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Initiate Feedback" onclick="google.script.run.sendMessage(ManagerID,proNo,proName)"
```

will not work because you are doing that within the HTML body. You are better of using a javascript code between `<script></script>` which would fetch the variables you need and then you can use the `google.script.run` in order to send out the email.

So you would then have

```
<script>
    function sender() {
      var ManagerID, proNo, proName;

      //use Document.getElementById in order to populate the variables with
      //what you need from the form

      google.script.run.sendMessage(ManagerID, proNo, proName);
    }
</script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Initiate Feedback" onclick="sender()">
```

The `<script></script>` part is supposed to be in your `index.html` as it is a client side script that will handle the calling of the server side script

I have done something similar and it works fine.